# Косноязычное высказывание методиста. Что является причиной коммуникативной ошибки?

Tags: коммуникативные-требования

«Учительница подошла к доске и попросила детей внимательно прочитать содержание таблицы».

Answer (score 6):

Алогизм -  смешение в одной фразе конкретного и отвлечённого планов:

*Учительница подошла к доске и попросила детей внимательно прочитать содержание таблицы*. 
Читать надо было не содержание, а саму таблицу.

Answer (score 2):

1. Вместо "содержания" надо было сослаться на содерж**имо**е.
2. Чтобы "прочитать" это содержимое, детям нужно дополнительное указание, в какой последовательности его читать: столбец за столбцом, построчно (если клетки таблицы вообще упорядочены по горизонтали и вертикали) или ещё как-то (напр. запомнить всё, что найдётся в клетках таблицы).

Answer (score 2):

В данном предложении допущена коммуникативная ошибка "смешение реального и идеального" (по классификации Б.М.Мучника). Содержание – это сумма идей и эмоций, т.е. нечто идеальное, не имеющее ни протяженности, ни веса, ни даже местоположения. Его, разумеется, нельзя прочитать. Читают не содержание, а саму таблицу (материальную вещь), как и, например, статью, книгу. Содержание же таблицы УСВАИВАЮТ, с ним ЗНАКОМЯТСЯ, им ОВЛАДЕВАЮТ. То есть с идеальным обращаются совсем не так, как с материальным. И поэтому слово «прочитать» применительно к содержанию абсолютно неуместно, не осмысленно.

Answer (score 1):

**Учительница попросила детей внимательно ознакомиться с содержанием таблицы, висевшей на доске.**

Походить к доске  для этого необязательно, если дети **сами** должны ознакомиться с таблицей.

***Прочитать таблицу*** ― не самое лучшее выражение, на таблицу чаще смотрят или изучают ее.

А вот ***прочитать содержание*** (но не таблицы, конечно) можно в некоторых случаях, например: прочитать краткое изложение романа, прочитать содержание сериала.

СОДЕРЖАНИЕ 3. То, что повествуется, что излагается, изображается где-л.; суть изложения, фабула. С. книги, доклада. С. оперы. С. разговора. Вот краткое с. этого фильма. Вам необходимо **ознакомиться с содержанием** этого письма, документа.

Comment: "Прочитать содержание сериала". Просторечие. Имеется в виду "Прочитать нечто, где описано содержание сериала".